# Analytics tracking code on a Jquery form button

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I'm trying to add GA tracking to the 'forward' and 'backward' buttons on a jquery form. The form progresses the user through screens but the page itself doesn't refresh therefore I'm using the _trackEvent method.

Each div 'screen' has an ID like so:

```
<div class="step" id="Basic_Information">
...form screen here
</div
```

And my button has no 'a href' attribute and looks like this:

```
<div id="bottom-area">
<button type="button" name="backward" id="backward" class="backward">Backward</button>
<button type="button" name="forward" id="forward" class="forward">Forward </button>
</div>
```

Here is the code I'm using but doesn't seem to work:

```
$('#Basic_Information #forward').click(function() {
gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'onpage-click', 'application-form', 'right']);
});
$('#Basic_Information #backward').click(function() {
gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'onpage-click', 'application-form', 'left']);
});
```

Can someone help explain where my syntax is going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: want to know that are you submitting the form on backward and forward button?

Comment: Element ID's need to be unique. You are using 2 ID's. That may be your problem. In other words `$('#forward').click()` should be enough. If you are reusing those forward and backward ID's on each screen, try appending the screen name like so `backward-basic-information` and `forward-basic-information`

Comment: Thanks for your response Kalish.

The forward/backward buttons stay constant and the form elements change on screen per the users progress. I'm trying to code for form abandonment, at what point people stop completing the form. 

In my example "Basic_Information" is the first bootstrap 'step' set of questions. The second 'step' is "Customer_Preference". The third is... and so on.

Since the buttons remain constant, how do I code to track the changing ID steps in the page?